# Show fieldset based on category script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys with this scipt i can hide it after you select a category or subcategory!

How to change this script to hide this in first and only show when selected the right category or subcategory?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#catId').change(function(){
    if( $('#catId').val() == "2" || $('#catId').val() == "3" || $('#catId').val() == "46" || $('#catId').val() == "48")
    {
    $("#indoor-specifications").hide();  // change Posted By with ID you give to the div
    }else
    {
    $("#indoor-specifications").show(); // change Posted By with ID you give to the div
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you chain a `.trigger("change")` (or just `.change()`) on the end of your existing `.change(function() {... })` that will call the function once immediately, thereby hiding the other control if appropriate.

Comment: what do you mean i do not understand sorry

Comment: I mean literally add `.trigger("change")` in between the closing `)` and `;` in your existing script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('#catId').on('change', function() {
   var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
   var valueSelected = this.value;
   if( (valueSelected == "2") || (valueSelected == "3") || (valueSelected == "46") || (valueSelected == "48")){
  $("#indoor-specifications").hide();
   }
   else{
     $("#indoor-specifications").show();
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="catId">
    <option value="2">One</option>
    <option value="3">Two</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 <option value="6">Six</option>
</select>

<br />

<div id="indoor-specifications">Hello World</div>
```